# Role based menu in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a menu that follows this structure:

```
 <div id="sidebar-menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="index.html" class="design active"><i class="icon-employee"></i><span> Employees </span></a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="Holiday.html" class="design"><i class="icon-holiday"></i><span> Holidays <span class="badge">6</span></span></a>
                </li>

                <li class="has_sub">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="design"><i class="icon-time"></i> <span> Time & Attendance </span> <span class="pull-right"><i class="mdi mdi-plus"></i></span></a>
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li><a href="incident.html">Incidents</a></li>
                        <li><a href="hour.html">Hours</a></li>
                        <li><a href="pass.html">Passes</a></li>
                        <li class"active"><a class"active" href="disability.html">Disabilities</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

There is a good article about how to create it but its just one level menu, here is a two level menu. http://techbrij.com/role-based-menu-asp-net-mvc

I would like to show it dynamically depending on user role or validation.

> Any clue or example on how to do it?

Answer (score 3):

To show things dynamically in any view based on user role. You may do something like this:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("roleName"))
{
    //Here you can write anything you want to show.
    <li><a href="incident.html">Incidents</a></li>
    <li><a href="hour.html">Hours</a></li>
    <li><a href="pass.html">Passes</a></li>
} else {
    <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
}
```

If you only want to check if the user is authenticated, you can do it like this:

```
@if (@User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //Here you can write anything you want to show.
    <li><a href="incident.html">Incidents</a></li>
    <li><a href="hour.html">Hours</a></li>
    <li><a href="pass.html">Passes</a></li>
} else {
    <li><a href="signup.html">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a></li>
}
```

If the menu is completely different it will be nice to do 2 partial views and call them from the _Layout depending on the user role or if the user is authenticated. Here is an example:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("roleName"))
{
    //Here you can write anything you want to show.
    @Html.Partial("_RoleXXMenu")
} else {
    @Html.Partial("_RoleYYMenu")
}
```